# Component Renders too early

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I have a class that does a lot of API Calls to populate the state so I'm doing it in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook like this:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    await this.populateQuote();
    await this.populateCustomers();
    await this.populateEmployees();
    await this.populatePropertyTypes();
}
```

and each of this functions are getting some data and setting some values in the state, now my problem is that every time one of the promises resolves it re-renders the page which I'd like to avoid, is there any way around this?

Comment: You should not setState in api methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Promise.all()` to fetch all data and then `this.setState()` to perform the only re-render

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const [quote, customers, employees, propertyTypes] = await Promise.all([
    this.populateQuote(),
    this.populateCustomers(),
    this.populateEmployees(),
    this.populatePropertyTypes()
  ]);

  this.setState({
    quote, 
    customers, 
    employees, 
    propertyTypes
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use `Promise.all` to ensure that all `Promises` in an array gets resolved before perform an operation

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const calls = [call1(), call2(), call3()]
    const results = await Promise.all(calls)
    console.log(results[0],results[1],results[2])
}
```

Comment: Each function is an api call and is setting some other values in the state, so as soon as one finishes it updates the state regardless and it triggers a re render

Comment: @MosesSchwartz it triggers re-render, it dont trigger re-componentDidMount though. If you are worried about re-rendering part, you should batch all of your setState once Promise.all resolves

Comment: `Promise.all` will ensure all gets resolved. You could put the logic inside a single `then` block. Not the prettiest solution but will get the job done

Answer (score 4):

What you could use is [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), to initiate parallel requests for your async calls.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const [quotes, customers, employees, propertyTypes] = await Promise.all([
        this.getQuotes(),
        this.getCustomers(),
        this.getEmployees(),
        this.getPropertyTypes()
    ]);
}
```

And then you would set corresponding state based on your results. This can be achieved only if your calls are independent of other async results (if next is dependent on previous, you'll have to await each function and pass it required result from previous call).

Most important thing for your answer is that you should not call `setState` before fetching all required results, because each call to `setState` initiates new render.